# VIM - Reformat text to one line paragraphs

Tags: vim

I have a text file like the following:

```
--------
FOX&DOGS

The quick brown. Fox
jumped.
Over the lazy dogs.
-------------------
```

I want to change it as follow:

```
--------
FOX&DOGS

The quick brown. Fox jumped.
Over the lazy dogs.
-------------------
```

So in general:

- preserve empty line/lines
- have new-lines just after any period_newline ".\n" (end of paragraph... In the above example I don’t want to cut line after "brown." for instance: there is just a period but not followed by newline, so it isn’t an end of a paragraph, so it has to stay on the same line)

My solution:

```
%s/\n\n/@\r@\r/ | %s/\.\n/\.@\r/ | %j | s/@ /\r/g | $$d
```

The idea is a bit rude:

- mark all ends of paragraph and empty lines (I have chosen "@" as marker)
- join all lines in a long single one
- substitute the marker "@ " (there is a space after @) with carriage return "\r" (newline)
- delete last empty line created during this procedure

It seemed to work so I also created an alias in vimrc:

```
command Par %s/\n\n/@\r@\r/ | %s/\.\n/\.@\r/ | %j | s/@ /\r/g | $$d
```

The problem:
If there aren’t any empty lines it returns error "pattern not found", and it doesn’t change anything. Seems a sort of conditional instruction is needed (if you find pattern substitute it with... else don't stop, continue with the other commands).

Any idea to solve in a simple way?

Comment: What do you mean by "one line paragraphs"? The desired output you have shown has a paragraph with two lines.

Comment: They are 2 paragraph: I mean a paragraph as text ending with a period followed by carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found a solution:

- add a blank line after the last one, so that the pattern *“\n\n”* is always found even if it isn’t present in the original file, and the error can’t block next commands.
- in the end we will have to remove 2 blank lines at the bottom created by the substitution *“s/@ /\r/g”*

So the command I tried is:

```
$ | put _ | %s/\n\n/@\r@\r/ | %s/\.\n/\.@\r/ | %j | s/@ /\r/g | $$d | $$d
```

- *$* go to the last line
- append a blank line
- mark newlines involving blank lines (also last blank line added) with @ character
- mark newlines involving period (the last line can’t end with period due to the marker @ added at the previous step)
- join all lines in a long one
- replace markers *“@ ”* with a newline (here we creates two more blank lines at the bottom, have to be removed)
- remove the two last blank lines added

Limitations:

if a paragraph ends with a punctuation mark other than “period”, it doesn’t work at all.

Any idea to improve my raw oneliner is welcome!